# Dialogue box to appear when any entry has been made into columns AR, BR, CR , DR

Tags: vba, excel

This would be easy for Excel Experts... I want to have a dialogue box to appear when any entry has been made into columns  M , AR, BR, CR , DR ... KR

It would be more nice if i get what entry has been made to the column in the dialogue box to appear...that is secondary if possible

These columns will be filled by Text by another formula...and this will be very rare

so, I just want to know by warning message if those cells get filled by text in future.

any help with code is appreciated :)

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Bhshan
What have you tried so far? 
Definitely this requires VBA code, and can't be doe by formulas. Don't expect SO to be your code writing service.

Comment: OK sorry guys if I was unambiguous before.
Let me explain in brief.

There are 12 columns for 12 months as M, AR, BR, .... KR

M has formula =IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(S8,N:N,1,FALSE)),S8,)

it looks for some value in columns S,

similarly, AR has formula =IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(AO7,AJ:AJ,1,FALSE)),AO7,)

it will look for value in column AJ

BR will look in CJ...

Now, thing is it is not necessary that this S, AJ, BJ ... KJ will have text in them.
It is rare that there will be entry in S, AJ, ..KJ

I just want to be notified by Display box in case there is text in columns S, AJ, BJ..KJ

Comment: @dgorti 
I have tried this one


Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Excel.Range)

If Worksheets("sheet1").Range("M7").Value = "" Then
Exit Sub
Else
MsgBox ("There was one or more rejections")
End If

End Sub


this works with just single cell... i want to make this work for 12 columns M, AR, BR, CR... KR for same sheet.

Answer (score 0):

Press Alt+F11
Click on this workbook and paste this macro:

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
        Select Case Target.Column
            Case 13, 44, 70, 96 'M, AR, BR, CR
                MsgBox ("You have altered column " & Target.Address & " with value: " & Target.Value)
        End Select

End Sub
```

Comment: You should consider protecting those columns and lock the sheet so they cant be overwritten. (you can unprotect all the cells that you want people to be able to edit.)